# Problem in detecting swipe gesture on recyclerView, MotionEvent e1 is null?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have a `recyclerView` along with a `tabLayout`. when user navigates through tabs, the `recyclerView` is loaded with new items. What I want now, is add the swipe feature so when the user swipes to right or left on the `recyclerView`, the app switches between tabs (and reload `recyclerView` with new Items). I have had a tough time trying to efficiently detect swipe (right/left) gestures on a `recyclerView`. I don't want to use ViewPager because I want to keep my app light and fast. besides the only feature I want, is only swipe. So here is the last method I have used:

```
OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity())
    {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            //update recyclerview with new data
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft(){
            //update recyclerview with new data
        }
    };

b.rcvItems.setOnTouchListener(onSwipeTouchListener);



b.rcvItems.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0) {
                int threshold = 20;
                int count = adapter.getItemCount();
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (lastVisible >= count - threshold) { 
                    //load more items
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is the class `OnSwipeTouchListener` within which is the class `GestureListener`:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

protected OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}





private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 23;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Now the problem is when the `Fragment` is loaded, in the first place, the swipe feature doesn't work. But after I scroll the `recyclerView`, or sometimes after I try to swipe many times, it starts to detect the swipes! And then it goes soft and smooth. I checked and noticed that the first parameter MotionEvent e1 in the method `onFling()` is null until I first scroll my `recyclerView` or after many swipe attempts. Still at some launches, the swipe feature works fine even in the very first place! (It's rare but it happens). It's so hacky and I can't even figure out the right behavior. How can I fix the issue?

**Side note**: Sometime the app freezes and then crashes. And I get the following crash log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionMyViewHolder{779d2db position=27 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{2415051 VFED..... ........ 0,0-1080,2049 #7f09016d app:id/rcvItems}, adapter:ui.adapter.ItemsAdapter@bee10b6, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@38c1b7, context:ui.MainActivity@577a61c
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5972)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6156)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:288)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:345)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:361)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:368)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:399)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Make OnSwipeTouchListener.kt :

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.GestureDetector
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import kotlin.math.abs
internal open class OnSwipeTouchListener(c: Context?) :
OnTouchListener {
   private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
   override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
      return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
   }
   private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
      private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD: Int = 100
      private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD: Int = 100
      override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
         return true
      }
      override fun onSingleTapUp(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
         onClick()
         return super.onSingleTapUp(e)
      }
      override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
         onDoubleClick()
         return super.onDoubleTap(e)
      }
      override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
         onLongClick()
         super.onLongPress(e)
      }
      override fun onFling(
         e1: MotionEvent,
         e2: MotionEvent,
         velocityX: Float,
         velocityY: Float
      ): Boolean {
         try {
            val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
            val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
            if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY)) {
               if (abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(
                  velocityX
               ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
            ) {
               if (diffX > 0) {
                  onSwipeRight()
               }
               else {
                  onSwipeLeft()
               }
            }
         }
          else {
            if (abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(
               velocityY
            ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
         ) {
            if (diffY < 0) {
               onSwipeUp()
            }
            else {
                  onSwipeDown()
                  }
               }
               }
         } catch (exception: Exception) {
         exception.printStackTrace()
      }
      return false
      }
   }
   open fun onSwipeRight() {}
   open fun onSwipeLeft() {}
   open fun onSwipeUp() {}
   open fun onSwipeDown() {}
   private fun onClick() {}
   private fun onDoubleClick() {}
   private fun onLongClick() {}
   init {
      gestureDetector = GestureDetector(c, GestureListener())
   }
}
```

### In MainActivity.kt

```
val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(this@MainActivity) {
         override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            super.onSwipeLeft()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Swipe Left gesture detected",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
         }
         override fun onSwipeRight() {
            super.onSwipeRight()
            Toast.makeText(
               this@MainActivity,
               "Swipe Right gesture detected",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
         }
         override fun onSwipeUp() {
            super.onSwipeUp()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Swipe up gesture detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
         }
         override fun onSwipeDown() {
            super.onSwipeDown()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Swipe down gesture detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
         }
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that e1 could be null for the initial movement so put it in try/catch block. And for the try/catch, check for null and return. Check below snippet

```js
if (e1 == null || e2 == null) 
  return false;
try {
...
} catch (Exception e) {}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tip above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68815311/2996699) I managed to override the Kotlin non nullable motion events with the Java Nullable annotation:

**MyGestureDetector.java**

```
public class MyGestureDetector implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

private final MyGestureDetectorCallBack onScrollDetectAction;

public MyGestureDetector(MyGestureDetectorCallBack onScrollDetectAction) {
    this.onScrollDetectAction = onScrollDetectAction;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(@NonNull MotionEvent e) { return false; }
@Override
public void onShowPress(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {}
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(@NonNull MotionEvent e) { return false; }

@Override
public boolean onScroll(@Nullable MotionEvent e1, @Nullable MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if (onScrollDetectAction != null) {
        try {
            onScrollDetectAction.onScrollNullable(e1, e2);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {}
@Override
public boolean onFling(@NonNull MotionEvent e1, @NonNull MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { return false; }}
```

In Java, we can manipulate the motion events as @Nullable.
Overriding onScroll in Kotlin is strict to @NotNull thus a compile error is shown.

**MyGestureDetectorCallBack.kt**

```
interface PSINTGestureDetectorCallBack {
    fun onScrollNullable(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?)
}
```

And then we just need to define the gesture detector on a **SwipeLayout.kt** (extending FrameLayout):

```
private val gestureDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestureDetectorCallBack)

private val gestureDetectorCallBack = MyGestureDetector(
    object : MyGestureDetectorCallBack {
        override fun onScrollNullable(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?) {
            //run your code
        }
    }
)

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    return false //depending on the requirements
}
```